# How does a camera pixel accumulate charge (colour)?

Tags: photodiode, camera, charge

I refer to the Wikipedia entry for a CMOS camera sensor's individual [pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_pixel_sensor). There is a schematic like so:-

[image: pixel]

and a statement that:-

> The read-out transistor, Msf, acts as a buffer (specifically, a source follower), an amplifier which allows the pixel voltage to be observed without removing the accumulated charge.

Where is this charge accumulated /stored?

Answer (score 3):

The charge is accumulated on all the capacitors connected to the cathode of the photodiode. This means:

- The source-bulk junction capacitance and gate-source overlap capacitance of \$M_{rst}\$
- The gate capacitance of \$M_{sf}\$
- The photodiode junction capacitance
- Any stray parasitic capacitances (eg. trace capacitance of the metal layers)

You usually want to have a small total capacitance to have the best signal-to-noise ratio for measuring the number of photogenerated charges stored on those capacitors.

Comment: Ah!  So rather than providing capacitors that have just been left off the schematic, the "pixel" uses available capacitance inherent in the components surrounding the photo diode?

Comment: And therefore it's a quality of manufacture thing than ensures capacitive consistency and thus a good image?

Comment: Yes, and often the photodiode itself is a main contributor to that capacitance. Any static errors can typically be compensated for in a post-processing step anyway, unlike noise, so the actual capacitance value is usually less important.

Comment: @PaulUszak capacitors require a lot of area. Photodiodes also take up a lot of area, and that one you're stuck with as you need it to collect light, so the idea is to build the photodiode such that you get the capacitor you need 'for free.'

Comment: @alex.forencich it's less applicable now though since they introduced backside illumination (they wouldn't necessarily block light anymore).